# C++ EnumWindows and then perform checks

Tags: c++, winapi

this code enums all windows.

```
BOOL CALLBACK enumWindowsProc(
__in  HWND hWnd,
__in  LPARAM lParam
)

{
  int length = ::GetWindowTextLength(hWnd);
  if (0 == length) return TRUE;

    TCHAR* buffer;
    buffer = new TCHAR[length + 1];
    memset(buffer, 0, (length + 1) * sizeof(TCHAR));
    GetWindowText(hWnd, buffer, length + 1);
    tstring windowTitle = tstring(buffer);
    string ns(windowTitle.begin(), windowTitle.end());
    string ns2 = "WinLister";
    const char *cstr = ns.c_str();
    const char *cstr2 = ns2.c_str();
    delete[] buffer;
    wcout << hWnd << TEXT(": ") << cstr << std::endl;
    wcout.clear();

    return TRUE;
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[]) {
wcout << TEXT("All Windows!") << endl;
BOOL enumeratingWindowsSucceeded = ::EnumWindows(enumWindowsProc, NULL);
cin.get();
return 0;
}
```

What i wanna do is after enumwindows to check if a specific window is opened. 
ex. if window WinLister is in the list then do smth. Tried some methods but i cant get it  working!

How can I perform checks to see if a specific window is opened?

FindWindow (classname, title) can't find the specific window I want. Only enumwidnows can get it!

Comment: Thanks for sharing the information. Simply implement the logic you want (i.e. compare against `ns2`, and do something to `hWnd` for a match) in your `enumWindowsProc`. Other than that, Stackoverflow is a Q&A site. Where's your question?

Comment: Wld hlp if u didn't abbvt so mch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `lParam` parameter to pass a user-defined value to the callback, like a pointer to a  `HWND` variable.  During the enumeration, the callback can update the value of that variable if the desired window is detected.  After the enumeration is finished, you can check the value of the variable and act accordingly.  For example:

```
BOOL CALLBACK FindTheDesiredWnd(HWND hWnd, LPARAM lParam)
{
    ...
    if (hWnd is the one you want)
    {
        *(reinterpret_cast<HWND*>(lParam)) = hWnd;
        return FALSE; // stop enumerating
    }
    return TRUE; // keep enumerating
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    HWND hFoundWnd = NULL;
    ::EnumWindows(&FindTheDesiredWnd, reinterpret_cast<LPARAM>(&hFoundWnd));
    if (hFoundWnd != NULL)
    {
        ...
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your `enumeratingWindowsSucceeded` variable is misleading. `EnumWindows` can return `FALSE` in case of success as well, if the `enumWindowsProc` callback returns `FALSE` to stop enumeration (which it usually does if you are using it to find a specific window).

Comment: You wrote: "if (hWnd is the one you want)" how can i get it?

Comment: You already have code to retrieve a window's title, you would simply perform string comparisons of those values until you find what you are looking for.

Comment: Note in Visual Studio the line `((HWND*)lParam)* = hWnd;` results with a `expression expected` error message. You should place the last dereference operator at the beginning of the line instead.

Comment: @mickaelb91 fixed

Answer (score 0):

EnumWindows enumerates only top-level windows. If the specific window you're looking for isn't a top-level window (e.g. it's a dialog), then EnumWindows won't work.

Comment: Its not a dialog. its a top lvl window